# Using FFmpeg to convert video to image sequence- getting error "<file name.mov> no such file or directory"

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to take a 10s `.mov` file and convert it to a series of multiple images for analysis using `ffmpeg`.  I've tried fiddling around with the line:

```
ffmpeg -i <file name.mov> -vf fps=1 out%d.png
```

but instead of any results, I keep getting the error

```
<file name.mov>: No such file or directory.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your input file?

Comment: Navigate to the directory containing `file name.mov` and try again. Because the example has a space you will have to quote or escape it: `ffmpeg -i "file name.mov"`